# Is $\sigma(A)$ similar to $A$ when $\sigma$ is a permutation of degree $n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

We know that if $A$ is a matrix with rows $A_1, ..., A_n$, then $\sigma(A)$ is a matrix with rows $A_{\sigma(1)}, ..., A_{\sigma(n)}$.

Actually, one can show that $\sigma(A) = \sigma(I)A$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. So, it seems that the answer to my question is negative, but I do not know why I feel that the answer should be yes.

We know that $A$ and $B$ are similar when there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that $A = PBP^{-1}$.

Any hint?

Comment: Do you have a precise definition of "similar" you're working with here?

Comment: Hint: What if $A=I$, and $\sigma$ is any permutation other than the identity? Is there any matrix similar to $I$ other than itself?

Comment: Your feeling that it "should be" yes might be because if you permute the rows and _then_ permute the columns in the same way, you _do_ get a similar matrix.

Comment: @Billy I edited the question to define "similarity".

Comment: @quasi I guess no! there is no other matrix similar to $I$ other than itself. But I did not get your hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=I$, and let $\sigma$ be any permutation other than the identity matrix.

Then $\sigma(A)=\sigma(I)\ne I$, hence $\sigma(A)$ is not similar to $A$ (since the only matrix similar to $I$ is $I$ itself).

Comment: Thanks! Now, I get it!